# Office Deployment Tool (ODT) 2019 Download Updates Only

Tags: microsoft-office, odt

I've successfully downloaded the `Office 2019` using `Office Deployment Tool (ODT) 2019`, but when an update was available, the script re-downloaded a `complete new` (but updated) Office 2019.

I don't want the script to download `all the files` when updates are available. I want it to download the `updates only`, so I can save `bandwidth`.

Please help. Thanks.

Configurations.xml file:

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019">
    <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="VisioPro2019Volume">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="ProofingTools">
      <Language ID="ar-sa" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" />
  <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

Command (in a batch-file):

```
Setup.exe /download Configurations.xml
```

Example: If office has 3 files, I want ODT to download and update `File 3` only, instead of downloading all the 3 files:

| Office version 2001.1111 | Office version 2104.13929 |
| --- | --- |
| File 1 version 1.0 | File 1 version 1.0 |
| File 2 version 1.0 | File 2 version 1.0 |
| File 3 version 1.0 | File 3 version 2.1 |

Note: I posted this question with a bounty previously on [StacksOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370985/office-deployment-tool-odt-2019-download-updates-only), but did not get an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want the update, download the update through Office itself, the ODT is working as designed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such configuration options for ODT to set to download update files only.

I do not think running ODT with configuration file could just download the update files for other versions, it would download whole installation content.

The ODT would download only the missing files instead of whole installation content when you download Office to a source path, the folder that already contains one specificed version. More information, please refer to following screenshot from "[SourcePath attribute (part of Add element)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office-deployment-tool-configuration-options#sourcepath-attribute-part-of-add-element)"

[image]

To achieve your needs of downloading update files only, it's recommended to use commands to invoke Office's own process (Such as `OfficeC2RClient.exe` or `OfficeClickToRun.exe`.) to check updates.

Here is the documentation about Office 2019 updates, "[Update Office 2019 (for IT Pros)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/update)". It says, there is a scheduled task named “Office Automatic Updates 2.0 ”, and it would start a program "OfficeC2RClient.exe" to updates, and Office would download what’s needed to update Office 2019 to the latest version.

[image]

Sometimes, we could enter `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.xxxxx.xxxxx` in Run dialog to update Office.

"xxxxx.xxxxx" means the build number, for example, [Version 2104 (Build 13929.20386)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019#retail-versions-of-office-2016-c2r-and-office-2019), we could write "13929.20386".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will test it as soon as an update is available.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft article
[Overview of the Office Deployment Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-office-deployment-tool)
explains how to use the ODT to update an installation to a newer version
from a folder.

This is covered in the section
[Update Microsoft 365 Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-office-deployment-tool#update-microsoft-365-apps):

> **Update Microsoft 365 Apps**
>
> You can use the Office Deployment Tool to make updates to your client
> computers after installing Microsoft 365 Apps. There are two ways to
> make the updates:
>
> - Use the ODT to install Microsoft 365 Apps again, which will update Office to the newest version. Only the files that have changed in the
>   new version will be updated.
> - Use the ODT to download the Office installation files and then point your client computers to that location to receive their updates. (By
>   default, clients are updated directly from the Office Content Delivery
>   Network (CDN).)
>
> To change where your client computers receive their updates, run the
> ODT in configure mode and specify an update path in the configuration
> file. For example, to have Microsoft 365 Apps get updates
> automatically from a network share called `\\server\updates`, include
> the following line in your configuration.xml file:
>
> ```
> <Updates Enabled="TRUE" UpdatePath="\\server\updates" />
> ```

To use configure mode, use the command:

```
setup.exe /configure installconfig.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am already using the command that you wrote, and it is working. My problem is that I want to update the main setup files without having to redownload the whole package.

Comment: If there is a way to do that, it might require using the [ExcludeApp directive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-office-deployment-tool#exclude-or-remove-microsoft-365-apps-applications-from-client-computers) to download only part of Office, then use the downloaded data to update without the ExcludeApp directive.